# What happens if $ a^2 > M^2 $ in Kerr metric?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, causality, singularities, kerr-metric

(Boyer-Lindquist coordinates and $ c = G =1 $ taken)

As I know, line element in Kerr metric $ d s^2 = - \left( 1 - \frac{2Mr}{\rho^2} \right) d t^2 - \frac{4 M a r \sin^2 \theta}{\rho^2} d \phi d t + \frac{\rho^2}{\Delta} d r^2 + \rho^2 d \theta^2 + \left( r^2 + a^2 + \frac{2 M r a^2 \sin^2 \theta}{\rho^2} \right) \sin^2 \theta d \phi^2 $ where $ a = \frac{J}{M}, \rho^2 = r^2 + a^2 \cos^2 \theta, \Delta = r^2 - 2 M r + a^2 $ suggests that causality breaks where $ r = M \pm \sqrt{M^2 - a^2} $.

How should I handle when $ a^2 > M^2 $ so $ r $ is complex?

For example, the Sun's mass, $ M_\odot \approx 1.5 \text{km} $ while it's angular momentum, $ J_\odot \approx 4.7 * 10^{19} \text{km}^2 > M_\odot ^2 $.

Will black holes with angular momentum bigger than mass squared not form an event horizon?

Comment: As an aside: $4 M a r sin^2 \theta$ would look better as   $4 M a r \sin^2 \theta$. Just using `\sin` instead of `sin`.

Comment: Editted. Thanks for the advise. @JosBergervoet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: BTW, the Sun's Schwarzschild radius, is ~2.95325007702 km

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mass is in the form of a material body like the earth where the spin parameter is $\rm a=J c/(G M)=890 M$, it would have to lose some angular momentum until $\rm a<M$ before it could collapse into a black hole, otherwise it can't since the centrifugal repulsion is larger than the centripetal attraction.

If the mass is in the form of a singularity that would be a [naked singularity](https://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=595#p595), and if it is an [elementary particles](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0507109) like the electron where $\rm a$ is many orders of magnitudes larger than $\rm M$ and $\rm r=0$ as well the close field should be [gravitationally repulsive](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A24093+reissner+nordstr%C3%B6m+repulsion).

Answer (score 0):

a > m can not occur in Kerr metric.
Most of spinning black holes have a Kerr parameter $\bar{a}=\frac{a}{m}$ close to 0.
According to Kerr himself, bodies with $ \bar{a}\ge 1 $ do not exist in the universe.

Hoping to have answered your question,

Best regards.